# What does Hinduism say about fishing and hunting?

Tags: animals

I am wondering, what does Hinduism say about sports fishing ?

Comment: Fishing for leisure is a sin. However fishing for a living is not.  There are ample references of the fisherman caste in our scriptures. Same is the case of hunting for a living. Hunting for leisure, gambling & indulging in sex with maidservants are stereotyped as inborn defects of kshatriyas, similar to how alcoholism, non-vegetarianism & inability to maintain orthodoxy are stereotyped as inborn defects of shudras.